# find_by_sql not returning extra attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am using find_by_sql to do a left join count on a relation like so:

```
scope :popular, lambda{ |since_date = false| 
      query = "select l.*, count(c.id) as popular_count from lists l left join choice_sets c on c.list_id = l.id and c.set_type = 'user'"
      query << "and c.updated_at > " + since_date.strftime("'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'") if since_date
      query << " group by l.id order by popular_count asc"
      find_by_sql(query)
  }
```

I am having trouble with the returned data not including the extra attribute `popular_count` in the attributes hash:

```
>  List.popular.first.attributes.keys
=> ["id", "name", "listtype", "slug", "description", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id"]
```

I believe I should be able to access `popular_count` in this attributes hash? I am using postgres.

Comment: You should be able to access it you're right.  Maybe ActiveRecord doesn't show it as an attribute in the attributes hash though.  If you try and call it directly do you get an error?

Comment: Yeah I get a not defined error... maybe its because I'm trying to call find_by_sql from inside a scope?

Comment: Maybe, but that would be odd.

Comment: Maybe you need a `attr_accessor :popular_count` on your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue on Rails 3.2 (not on Rails 4)

I have in `app/models/list.rb` a scope named `popular` and a class method named `pop`:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :popular, lambda{ |since_date = false| 
    query = "select l.*, count(l.id) as popular_count from lists l "
    query << "and l.updated_at > " + since_date.strftime("'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'") if since_date
    query << " group by l.id order by popular_count asc"
    self.find_by_sql(query)
}

  def self.pop
    since_date = false
    query = "select l.*, count(l.id) as popular_count from lists l "
    query << "and l.updated_at > " + since_date.strftime("'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'") if since_date
    query << " group by l.id order by popular_count asc"
    find_by_sql(query)
  end
```

end

In the console, `popular` doesn't have `popular_count` as an attribute:

> 2.0.0-p353 :002 > List.popular.first.attributes.keys
>
> List Load (0.2ms)  select l.*, count(l.id) as popular_count from lists l group by l.id order by popular_count asc
>
> List Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "lists".* FROM "lists"
>
> => ["id", "name", "created_at", "updated_at"]

While the class method `pop` does:

> 2.0.0-p353 :001 > List.pop.first.attributes.keys
>
> List Load (0.6ms)  select l.*, count(l.id) as popular_count from lists l group by l.id order by popular_count asc
>
> => ["id", "name", "created_at", "updated_at", "popular_count"]

So, if using Rails 4 is not an option, I would suggest to use a class method as a workaround.